# Resizing multiple elements relative to a vertex?

Tags: javascript, css, geometry, resize, scale

Context: I am building a design tool and have a group resizing feature.

Video: https://share.getcloudapp.com/v1ux6247

What should happen: https://share.getcloudapp.com/5zuweGnG

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-https-ll95b?file=/src/Resizer.tsx

I am getting stuck with the geometry behind solving this problem. I asked the question the Math channel, but I am having a hard time converting this awesome answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3843990/calculate-y-position-from-hypotenuse to the fiddle.

If you have a fixed vertex (top right corner) and a scaling point (bottom left corner) then all the elements in the box should scale nicely -- without using the CSS "scale property", which wouldn't work, because it needs to move on the x and y-axis. It should scale using CSS width, height, and x/y transforms.

I am hoping to learn the proper solution to this. If you want to take a stab at it or have the geometric wisdom, then I would very much appreciate you sharing that with me and the community.

*A code snippet taking an attempt to get the dimensions right*

```
// Clearly my numbers are off here and I am thinking about it incorrectly
const handleUpdateNodes = ({ node, item, c }: any) => {

  // setting the points you can find the item properties here https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-https-ll95b?file=/src/App.tsx:360-453
  const vertexes: any = {
    tl: [item.left, item.top],
    tr: [item.width + item.left, item.top],
    bl: [item.left, item.height + item.top],
    br: [item.width + item.left, item.height + item.top]
  };

  // playing around with scaling the points based on c which is the scale i.e 0.5
  const { tl, tr, bl } = scaleVertexes(vertexes, c);

  if (node) {
    // top right x point minus the top left x point = new width
    node.style.width = `${tr[0] - tl[0]}px`;

    // left is the original left / the scale change I messed this whole x,y up confused here
    node.style.transform = `translate(${item.left / scale}px, ${item.top}px)`;

    // bottom left y minus top left y
    node.style.height = `${bl[1] - tl[1]}px`;
  }
};
```

*Here is a rough diagram to illustrate. The videos and fiddle describe what is going on better.*

[image]

Comment: Ok I think I have a solid solution. Open to feedback, will answer my own question soon https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-https-ll95b?file=/src/Resizer.tsx